# Implementing a python class

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a personal project and I am having trouble implementing this following part.

Implementing a Menu Class.

This class will make use of MenuItem objects.

This class represents the restaurant menu which contains 4 different categories of menu item diners can order from.
This class will have a single class(or static) variable:

- **Menu_Item_types:** a list containing 4 strings representing the 4 possible types of menu items.: Drink, appetizer, entree, dessert.

This class will use the following instance attribute:

- List item

  **self.menuItemDrinkList:** list of all drink list

  **self.menuItemAppetizerList:** list of all appetizer list

  **self.menuItemEntreeList:** a list of all entree list

  **self.menuItemDessertList:** a list of all the dessert list

Below is the menuItem object

```
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, name=None, types=None, price=None, description=None):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.price = price
        self.description = description

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def setTypes(self, types):
        self.types = types

    def getTypes(self):
        return self.types

    def setPrice(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.price

    def setDescription(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.description

    def __str__(self):

        return "{} ({}): ${}, {}".format(self.name, self.types, self.price, self.description)
```

Comment: what is the question? and why all the getters/setters? this is not Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for setters and getters properties. Here is the way how you do it in Python.
You can learn more about properties [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, name=None, types=None, price=None, description=None):
        self._name = name
        self._types = types
        self._price = price
        self._description = description

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def types(self):
        return self._types

    @types.setter
    def types(self, types):
        self._types = types

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, price):
        self._price = price

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

    @description.setter
    def description(self, description):
        self._description = description

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({}): ${}, {}".format(
            self._name, self._types, self._price, self._description
        )


menu_item = MenuItem("pizza", "entry", 10)
print(menu_item)

menu_item.price = 20
menu_item.description = "Delicious"
print(menu_item)
```

output:

```
pizza (entry): $10, None 
pizza (entry): $20, Delicious
```

Please notice:

- In python you don't call properties with getXxx or setXxx, you just use regular names and decoreate methods with **@property** and **@xxx.setter**
- You should have **@property** before **@setter**.
- Setter must start with the property name
- In order to escape recursion, name your internal
  attributes with _ (_name). If you will not do it you will have a
  "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"
  because setter will call itself in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I recently followed a tutorial that set the setter and getter attribute. They never mentioned using properties.